# Rails ActiveRecord : change the ruby class used for the collection after a join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's say I have these models, which have associations between them :

```
class Book
  belongs_to :publisher
  belongs_to :author
end

class Publisher
  has_many :books
end

class Author
  has_many :books
end
```

I have written a query like this :

```
def get_old_authors_at_publisher(publisher, date)
  publisher
    .books
    .joins(:author)
    .where('"book"."publication_date" < ?', date)
end
```

The problem is that this query returns Books but I want Authors. It should be possible to make Authors out of the result of the query, because all columns are accessible (something like `SELECT "authors".*` should work), but I can't figure how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a has_many through association to the Publisher model:

```
class Publisher
  has_many :books
  has_many :authors, through: :books
end
```

Then you can use it from an instance of Publisher:

```
publisher.authors.where('books.publication_date < ?', 5.years.ago)
```